# Having an issue reading a string from a file of names in C

Tags: c, file-io

I am reading through a text file that has a line on each name. I need to generate a random number from 0-99 to determine the index of the name to choose. When I use the method fscanf() and then I try to display the string that I read, a blank string is outputted. I have tested it and I am entering the if statement to assign the string to the variable, there just seems to be an issue with assigning the name.

```
int indexOfName = rand() % 100;
        printf("%d\n", indexOfName);

        FILE *fileOfNames;
        char str[30];
        char *filename = "theFilePath";

        fileOfNames = fopen(filename, "r");
        rewind(fileOfNames);
        if (fileOfNames == NULL)
        {
            printf("Could not open file %s", filename);
            return 1;
        }
        int i = 0;
        while (fgets(str, 30, fileOfNames) != NULL)
        {
            if (i == indexOfName)
            {
                fscanf(fileOfNames, "%s", str);
            }
            i++;
        }
        printf("%s\n", str);
        fclose(fileOfNames);
        return 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `break` after `if (i == indexOfName)`. Otherwise, you will just overwrite str until you reach the end of the file.

You probably don't even want `fscanf` in the `if` statement as `while (fgets(str, 30, fileOfNames) != NULL)` writes the line to str allready.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has 2 problems:

1) It continues overwriting `str` after it finds the right entry.  You can avoid this by stopping after iterating up to `indexOfName`.

2) After it assigns the right value to `str`, it overwrites it again with the call to `fscanf`.

It also probably makes more sense to use a for loop for this, since you want a specific number of iterations.  You can make your code work correctly by replacing the while loop with this for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < indexOfName; i++) fgets(str, 30, fileOfNames);
```